# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated error

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Hi I'm working on wordpress theme and write a custom widget it's working properly. But when I make wp_debug = true it's giving this error

Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in ....

Here is the my preg_replace code

```
$status = preg_replace("/((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[^ )]+)/e", "'<a href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\" $target >'. ((strlen('$1')>=$linkMaxLen ? substr('$1',0,$linkMaxLen).'...':'$1')).'</a>'", $status);
```

I'm trying change it like this

```
$status = preg_replace_callback(
                "/((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[^ )]+)/e",
                function($matches) {
                    return "'<a href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\" $target >'. ((strlen('$1')>=$linkMaxLen ? substr('$1',0,$linkMaxLen).'...':'$1')).'</a>'";
                },
                $status
            );
```

But it's not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: use preg_replace_callback instead, see the documentation.

Comment: I tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback, substitute `$1`  by `$matches[1]`:

```
function($matches) {
    return "'<a href=\"$matches[1]\" title=\"$matches[1]\" $target >'
        . (
            ( strlen($matches[1]) >= $linkMaxLen ? 
                  ? substr(matches[1], 0, $linkMaxLen).'...'
                  : matches[1]
            )
          )
        .'</a>'"
},
```